# Specifying Graph Edges Should Not Overlap Vertices

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, labeling, style

In the options for `GraphPlot` and related functions, it seems `EdgeShapeFunction` overwrites a `VertexSize` specification. Consider the following.

1. Without an `EdgeShapeFunction` specification.

```
GraphPlot[
 CompleteGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True],
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> Placed[All, Center], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 14, VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
 VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> 0.2, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

The edges do not overlap with the vertices.

2. With an `EdgeShapeFunction` specification.

```
GraphPlot[
 CompleteGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True],
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> Placed[All, Center], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 14, VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
 VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> 0.2, ImageSize -> 200, 
 
EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  GraphElementData[{"UnfilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .05}]]
```

[image]

The edges overlap with the vertices.

---

Notice the code is identical except the second has the specification of `EdgeShapeFunction`. I want the `UnfilledArrow` specification of the second, but I do not want the edges to overlap the vertices, like in the first.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another work-around:  Add a second argument to `Arrow` objects to specify *setback*:

```
vertexSize = .02;

GraphPlot[CompleteGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True], 
 DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[All, Center], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 14,
 VertexShapeFunction -> None,  
 VertexSize -> vertexSize, 
 ImageSize -> 400, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (ReplaceAll[ Arrow[a_] :> Arrow[a, vertexSize]] @*
    GraphElementData[{"UnfilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .05}])]
```

[image]

With `vertexSize = .1` and `VertexLabelStyle -> 30` we get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A workaround:

```
GraphPlot[CompleteGraph[3, DirectedEdges -> True]
 , DirectedEdges -> True
 , VertexLabels -> Placed[All, Center]
 , VertexLabelStyle -> 14

 , VertexShapeFunction -> Automatic
 , VertexStyle -> Directive[White, EdgeForm[Transparent]]

 , VertexSize -> 0.2
 , ImageSize -> 400
 , EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  GraphElementData[{"UnfilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .05}]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]